# bash inner script ?inline? passing to interpreters new lines problem

Tags: bash

I have some bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
INTERPRETER=/home/user/bin/inter
TASKSET=/bin/taskset
BACKUP=/home/user/backup
SCRIPT='action 1;
        action 2;
        if 1;
           do something;
           do something else;
        fi;
        if 2; do something; do something else; fi;
        lambda1 {
           do something;
           do something;
           };
        lamda2 {do....};
        exit 0;'
echo -e `$TASKSET -c 1,2 $INTERPRETER <<< "$SCRIPT"`
```

Problem is that formatted if 1 and lambda1 throws an error.
Flattened if2 and lamda2 works fine.

1. Is there an option to fix that new
   liners?
2. How this function '<<<' is called, what to look up in uncle google?

**EDIT**

```
echo -e "$SCRIPT" | $TASKSET.....
```

behaves this same wrong way.

Comment: Your example has unbalanced backticks in the last line.  Can you please correct it?  It will be easier to help you if you make a real script that is simple and shows the same problem.

Comment: `<<<` is called a [here string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Redirections)

Comment: `$SCRIPT` is being passed as input to `/home/user/bin/inter`.  So if newlines aren't doing what you expect, I the problem is caused by `inter`.

Comment: Thanks Mikel for the link, last line corrected.
The thing that iterpreter can handle this script when it's a real file.
user$> inter mytruescript.txt #Works fine.

Comment: From doc:"     <<< word

The word is expanded and supplied to the command on its standard input." this explains why it doesn't work. interpreter can't get code from stdin this way, just whole action in one line. Is there a work around?

Comment: @bua If the $INTERPRETER can't accept code from STDIN, consider `echo "$SCRIPT" > $TEMPFILE` and feed $TEMPFILE to the $INTERPRETER

Comment: This looks like a problem with how `$TASKSET` handles stdin. Does it read one line and try to evaluate it immediately?

Answer (score 1):

The other general form of a here string (aka here document) is

```
<<word
```

an example of this form is:

```
cat <<EOF
This is some text that I want to pass to cat
EOF
```

In this format of the here doument, no expansion or substitution is performed.

What language is /home/user/bin/inter interpreting? How does that interpreter react to linefeeds and escaped linefeeds?

Comment: It's custom interpreter, but the LF (CRLF on win) is part of the language syntax.